# FOSUserBundle User addGroup does not save in the database

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to add users to role groups but for some reason I cannot achieve this.
I followed the documentation on symfony website http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html. The object is created and it's correct but on flush nothing happens.

UserRoleGroups are already defined in the DB.

> saving

```
$oGroup = $this->em->getRepository('UserBundle:UserRoleGroups')->findOneByName($sRole);

$oUser->addGroup($oGroup);
$this->em->persist($oUser);
$this->em->flush();
```

Any other changes I do to $oUser object are saved except for this one.

> User Entity

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\UserRoleGroups"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="users_user_role_group",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $userRolesGroup;
```

> UserRoleGroup Entity

```
class UserRoleGroups extends BaseGroup
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Comment: Please provide appropriate code.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the User Entity there was no `addUserRoleGroup` defined.

```
/**
 * @param UserRoleGroups $userRoleGroups
 */
public function addUserRoleGroup(UserRoleGroups $userRoleGroups) {
    $this->userRolesGroup->add($userRoleGroups);
}
```

So this should solve the problem.